Tkinter Issue With Entry Boxes Beginning With 0
Recently as a task for school we've been making a basic program with a GUI and classes but me and my classmates have run into an issue where if a zero is at the front of the entry it often breaks. Everything works perfectly fine other than this one scenario (to see an example run it and type "0111" into the student/senior entry and press total cost) and I was wondering what the reason for this is what should happen when you try to calculate the total is it shows the cost of the number of tickets you enter up to a max of 100 tickets, for some reason when a 0 is in front it gets unhappy. When "0111" is entered in the student entry box I would expect to see it say "Too many tickets" but instead it reads "0111" as "73"
I've tried fixing it via removing leading zeros of the "self.amt.get()" variable but I've found that it may be an issue with the entry box itself and that I can't actually access the value, I believe its a Tkinter issue but I'd happily be proven wrong, code is below:
from tkinter import *
#Program Title: Ticket Booking System
#Date: 7/5/24
#Purpose: To allow a user to book tickets for an event
#Version: 3.0
tickets = {}
pricing = {"Child":5,"Adult":15,"Student/Senior":10}
class Ticket:
    def __init__(self,type):
        self.type = type
        self.lbl_text = (f"{self.type}: ${pricing[self.type]}")
        self.amt = IntVar()
    def lbl_print(self):
        labels = Label(window,text=self.lbl_text)
        labels.grid(row=list(pricing.keys()).index(self.type),column=0,sticky="WE",ipady=8,ipadx=15)
    def ent_print(self):
        entries = Entry(window,textvariable=self.amt)
        entries.grid(row=list(pricing.keys()).index(self.type),column=1,sticky="WE",ipady=8,ipadx=15)
    def calculate(self):
        return ((self.amt.get())**2)**0.5 * pricing[self.type]
def calculate_total():
    global total_tickets
    total_tickets = 0
    for i in pricing:
        total_tickets += tickets[i].amt.get()
    if total_tickets > 100:
        total_lbl = Label(window, text="Too many tickets")
    else:
        total_cost = sum(tickets[i].calculate() for i in pricing)
        total_lbl = Label(window, text=f"${total_cost:.2f}")
    total_lbl.grid(row=len(pricing), column=1, sticky="WE", ipady=8, ipadx=15)
window = Tk()
window.title("Ticket Booking")
for i in pricing:
    tickets[i] = Ticket(i)
    tickets[i].lbl_print()
    tickets[i].ent_print()
calculate_total()
total_btn = Button(window, text="Calculate Total", command=calculate_total)
total_btn.grid(row=len(pricing), column=0, sticky="WE", ipady=8, ipadx=15)
window.mainloop()


Better edit the queston to explain what happens and what should happen.

It seems that tk interprets the number with leading 0 as octal notation (instead of decimal). Possible solution: Use a StringVar instead of IntVar and convert the string using Python's int function. This needs additional error checks if e.g. letters were entered and the string therefore can't be converted.

it is good practice, for clarity, to avoid wildcard imports:
wildcard imports pollute the namespace.
